# Can't read file without additional prefix on Intellij

Tags: file, intellij-idea, windows-8.1

I have met some strange trouble with reading file at Intellij Idea and on Windows 8.1.

And always I got `FileNotFoundException`.

Here is code snippet:

```
public XlsReader(String fileName, String sheetName) {
    open(fileName, sheetName);
}

public void open(String fileName, String sheetName) {
    InputStream fis = null;
    try {
        if (sheetName == null || sheetName.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please, provide sheet name");
        }
        Logger.logDebug("PATH: " + new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        String resourceFilePath = this.getClass().getResource(fileName).getFile();
        Logger.logDebug(resourceFilePath);
        fis = new FileInputStream(resourceFilePath);

        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);
        getMetaData();
```

I couldn't understand why at this line:

`new FileInputStream(fileName)`

I have got this exception.
And when chcenging path from:

> xls = new XlsReader("InputDataIndirect.xlsx", "Calculator");

to:

> xls = new XlsReader("test/InputDataIndirect.xlsx", "Calculator");

And it works now.

Here is project struckture:

[image]

I tried to load file from class path as well `this.getClass().getResource(fileName).getFile()` but it wasn't successful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you let us know what your directory structure is like? Where is the source code, and where does InputDataIndirect.xlsx live?

Comment: @Trisha I added project view.

Comment: If you're running a main method or test from inside IntelliJ idea, it uses the root of the project as the root to load files from. Therefore, it will look under new_automation, so you need to add the "test" folder to your path. To change this, you can change the working directory location in your run configuration. Alternatively, some of the comments and answers on this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094701/access-resource-folder-within-jar

Comment: @Trisha Changing working directory works just as charm. If you will write answer according your comment I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running a main method or test from inside IntelliJ idea, it uses the root of the project as the root to load files from. Therefore, it will look under `new_automation`, so you need to add the `test` folder to your path.

To change this, you can change the ***working directory location*** in your run configuration to the location you want it to look in for files.