# Access resource folder within jar

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, resources, gson

I am trying to read the contents of a `resource` folder once my JAR is built. The resource folder is marked as a `source` in the IDE settings (IntelliJ).

I have tried the following methods:

```
  InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../objectLocation.json");
  JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

I have also tried:

```
  JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("../resources/objectLocation.json"));
```

Both of these methods results in :

Which results in:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/layers/resources/objectLocation.json (No such file or directory)
```

File structure:

```
src

-com.layers -> myClasses

-resources -> JSON
```

EDIT:

```
  InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("objectLocation.json");
  JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

Results in a:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: I think you dont need the ".." because than you go outside of your source-location. Try `InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("objectLocation.json");` and if its located within subfolders of your ressource folder than `InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("<subfolder>/objectLocation.json");`

Comment: That results in a `java.lang.NullPointerException
`

Comment: Sry i missed the "/" -> `try .getResourceAsStream("/objectLocation.json");`

Comment: Try InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("./objectLocation.json");

Comment: That seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not understanding the difference between *absolute* and *relative* paths when loading resources in Java via `getResourceAsStream()` is a common source of errors leading to `NullPointerException`.

Assuming the following structure and content:

```
My Project
  |-src
    |-main
      |-java
      | |-SomePackage
      |   |-SomeClass.java
      |-resources
        |-Root.txt
        |-SomePackage
          |-MyData.txt
          |-SomePackage2
            |-MySubData.txt
```

Content will be re-organized as following in the .jar:

```
|-Root.txt
  |-SomePackage
    |-SomeClass.java
    |-MyData.txt
    |-SomePackage2
      |-MySubData.txt
```

The following indicates what works and what does not work to retrieve resource data:

```
InputStream IS;
IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("Root.txt"); // Not OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/Root.txt"); // OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/MyData.txt"); // Not OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("MyData.txt"); // OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/SomePackage/MyData.txt"); // OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("SomePackage/MyData.txt"); // Not OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("MySubData.txt"); // Not OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("SomePackage/SomePackage2/MySubData.txt"); // OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/SomePackage/SomePackage2/MySubData.txt"); // Not OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/SomePackage2/MySubData.txt"); // Not OK

IS = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("SomePackage2/MySubData.txt"); // OK
```

`getResourceAsStream()` operates relative to the package corresponding to the called Class instance.